# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `book_id`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this problem, but don't know why.
I create models with generator:

```
bin/rails generate model Book name:string author:string description:text cover:string
bin/rails generate model Episode name:string description:text art:string
ant other...
```

book.rb

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
has_many :episodes
end
```

episode.rb

```
class Episode < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :book
has_many :scenes
end
```

When in console i try to: `book.episodes << episode` i had an error: `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute "book_id"`
My schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170320111956) do
# These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
enable_extension "plpgsql"
create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
t.text     "text"
t.string   "next_scene"
t.string   "next_episode"
t.string   "voiceover"
t.integer  "end"
t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end
create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "author"
t.text     "description"
t.string   "cover"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
create_table "episodes", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.text     "description"
t.string   "art"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
create_table "scenes", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.text     "text"
t.integer  "choise"
t.string   "next_scene"
t.string   "next_episode"
t.string   "art"
t.string   "music"
t.string   "sound_fx"
t.string   "voiceover"
t.integer  "end"
t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end
end
```

In schema i haven't id_book, but why? I also do db:migrate and have error again.

Comment: You have to add book_id in Episode model

Comment: It's not auto added when i add "belongs_to :book"? Ok, thank's. It's work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Rails uses the convention of naming the primary as the autogenerated column `id`. If you wish to specify a different primary key, such as `book_id`, you could do the following:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = "book_id"
end
```